# Why isn't NULL being assigned to my array of pointers?

Tags: c

I have this C program in which the last position in the `*args` array must be NULL. The NULL isn't being assigned or maybe printed? Is it because `"%s"` doesn't work with NULL?

In the program below I'm splitting a user inputted string and assigning each token to the `*args` array of pointers. The last element shall be NULL.

Comment: The only way for the `for(;;)` loop to terminate is if token is NULL, which is assigned to args[counter] before the break.  You aren't attempting to print args[counter] due to the terminating predicate for the 2nd `for` loop. If you make the terminating condition `i<=counter`, then you can test `args[i]` within the loop to print something useful if it's NULL.

Comment: You don't increment `counter` when the token is `NULL`.

Comment: "*The NULL isn't being assigned*". How do you reach that conclusion? Your print loop stops at index `counter-1` whereas the NULL is at index `counter`. It's not a good idea to try and print a NULL pointer as a string anyway.

Comment: Why would you intentionally try to print using `NULL` pointer? For `%s`, "the argument shall be a pointer to the initial element of an array of character type" (C11: 7.21.6.1 The fprintf function). I would regard feeding `NULL` to cause undefined behaviour. But some library implementations might be very forgiving at this point.

Comment: shady, who or what text suggested `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", input);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted above you don't count the NULL (unless it was the first one; bug) so this means args[counter -1 ] will be the last non-NULL entry when you print it.  Here are some issues that I fixed:

- Replaced run flag with a break, which eliminated the need including stdbool
- args is subject to overflow
- It doesn't make sense to do a bunch of work on exit so moved that to right after input
- streamline strtok call, and fixed defect if first call returns NULL
- Prettify output including changing message "last character" to "last string".
- Replaced the two magic values of 81 with defines.

And a few issues not fixed:

- You use both a terminating null and a counter to significant number of elements in args.  Choose one or the other.
- scanf is subject to buffer overflow, replace it with fgets() and post-processing of input to to get the result of the format string.
- scanf("%[^\n]%*c", input); fails to read anything when input is "\n". It also lacks a width limit (@chux-ReinstateMonica).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_INPUT 81
#define MAX_ARGS 81

int main() {
    for(;;) {
        char input[MAX_INPUT];
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", input);
        if(!strcmp(input, "Exit")) break;

        int counter = 0;
        char *token;
        char *args[MAX_ARGS];
        do {
            token = strtok(counter ? NULL : input, " ");
            args[counter] = token;
            if(token) counter++;
        } while(token && counter < MAX_ARGS);
        if(counter == MAX_ARGS) {       
            counter--;
            args[counter] = NULL;
        }

        printf("\nlast string: %s\n", args[counter - 1]);
        for(unsigned i=0; i < counter; i++) {
            printf("%d %s\n", i, args[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```